# Adding margin to div does not move placement of background-image

Tags: css, background, background-image, margin

I'm trying to align the background image of a div to the top of the div, but it continues to align it to the top of either the parent div or the whole page (I'm not sure which one, but I think it's page)

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Minecraft_Percabeth/1wbuduze/2/

The background image of the #bottom div should show over the top of their heads, but instead the top is aligned to the top of the #wrap div. **Edit:** The image should also stay where it is when scrolling down, which is why I'm currently using fixed.

Change the margin-top to 0 to see what I mean.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>

#wrap {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 500px; width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
}
    #bottom {
        background: blue url("http://i.imgur.com/BsTVroc.jpg") fixed center top;
        height: 400px; width: 500px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
```

Comment: Would you like to move the background image down?

Comment: @lucajung99 Yes, I want the top of the image to coincide with the top of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **fixed** in
`background: blue url("http://i.imgur.com/BsTVroc.jpg") fixed center top;`

Is the shorthand for `background-attachment: fixed;`
That is why the background image is fixed to the top "the page".
Without this property the background image moves to `margin-top: 100px;`

**Edit:**

In order to move the background image vertically, you can use `background-position: center XY%;` and add again `background-attachment: fixed;`

```css
#bottom {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/BsTVroc.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 20%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
#wrap {
    background-color: #737373;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But now there's another problem, which I probably should've mentioned in the OP: I used fixed because I want it to stay in place when I scroll. Is there a way to move the background-image even when it's fixed, like you can with divs?

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope this is what you're searching for :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `background-position: center 100px;` - this will move the background image down by 100px.

Comment: Thanks you, I did not know you could use things other than "top, center, bottom" etc. for the position!